# Autofac instance per viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, inversion-of-control, autofac

I have a little problem with Autofac configuration. My goal is to create new `EFContext` per `ViewModel`

Right now I have:

```
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.Register(ctx => new EFContext())
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

builder.Register<FirstService>(c => new FirstService(c.Resolve<EFContext>()));
builder.Register<SecondService>(c => new SecondService(c.Resolve<EFContext>()));
builder.Register<OtherService>(c => new OtherService(c.Resolve<EFContext>()));

builder.Register<FirstViewModel>(c => 
            new FirstViewModel(
                c.Resolve<FirstService>(), 
                c.Resolve<SecondService>(), 
                c.Resolve<OtherService>()
            ));
builder.Register<SecondViewModel>(c => 
            new SecondViewModel(
                c.Resolve<FirstService>(), 
                c.Resolve<SecondService>(), 
                c.Resolve<OtherService>()
            ));
```

But now when I create `SecondViewModel` all services get the same `EFContext` as in `FirstViewModel` services

Comment: I'm not familiar with Autofac, but after a look into the documentation, shouldn't you be using `InstancePerDependency` instead of `InstancePerLifetimeScope` to get the desired behavior?

Comment: I've already tried with `InstancePerDependency` and it always creates new `EFContext`for every service object. And that is not my goal.

Comment: Oh right, should've read better. I might have a solution, but I cannot post it as comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I have my answer

There wasn't any problem with Autofac configuration but in  resolving dependency. Right now I have:

```
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.Register(ctx => new EFContext())
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

builder.Register<FirstService>(c => new FirstService(c.Resolve<EFContext>()));
builder.Register<SecondService>(c => new SecondService(c.Resolve<EFContext>()));
builder.Register<OtherService>(c => new OtherService(c.Resolve<EFContext>()));

builder.Register<FirstViewModel>(c => 
            new FirstViewModel(
                c.Resolve<FirstService>(), 
                c.Resolve<SecondService>(), 
                c.Resolve<OtherService>()
            ));
builder.Register<SecondViewModel>(c => 
            new SecondViewModel(
                c.Resolve<FirstService>(), 
                c.Resolve<SecondService>(), 
                c.Resolve<OtherService>()
            ));
```

And when I want resolve dependency I use:

```
using (var scope = Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
    var vm = scope.Resolve<FirstViewModel>();
}
```

Comment: Ah, I was already looking for a way to register the scoped viewmodels as single instance in the builder, but it seems you didn't even need that ;) You should mark this as answered if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 2):

I've made another attempt, and I think this is currently the best solution I can find.

Could you try and see if the following works for you (from the [Autofac Documentation](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html#instance-per-lifetime-scope))?

```
//First builder
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();

//Register context as Lifetime dependent.
builder.Register(ctx => new EFContext())
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

//Register services.
builder.Register<FirstService>(c => new FirstService(c.Resolve<EFContext>()));
builder.Register<SecondService>(c => new SecondService(c.Resolve<EFContext>()));
builder.Register<OtherService>(c => new OtherService(c.Resolve<EFContext>()));

//Build first builder to work with scopes.
var container = builder.Build();

//Create a second builder.
ContainerBuilder builder2 = new ContainerBuilder();

using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
    //Create services, since lambda is executed after scope is disposed.
    var firstService = scope.Resolve<FirstService>();
    var secondService = scope.Resolve<SecondService>();
    var otherService = scope.Resolve<OtherService>();

    //Register viewmodel with second builder.
    builder2.Register<FirstViewModel>(c => new FirstViewModel(
        firstService,
        secondService,
        otherService
    ));
}

using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
    //Create services, since lambda is executed after scope is disposed.
    var firstService = scope.Resolve<FirstService>();
    var secondService = scope.Resolve<SecondService>();
    var otherService = scope.Resolve<OtherService>();

    //Register viewmodel with second builder.
    builder2.Register<SecondViewModel>(c => new SecondViewModel(
        firstService,
        secondService,
        otherService
    ));
}

//Build second builder.
var container2 = builder2.Build();

//Merge registration of second builder with the first.
foreach (var registration in container2.ComponentRegistry.Registrations)
    container.ComponentRegistry.Register(registration);


//Resolve the viewmodels from the container.
var firstViewModel = container.Resolve<FirstViewModel>();
var secondViewModel = container.Resolve<SecondViewModel>();
```

An issue could be that the services (`FirstService`, `SecondService` and `OtherService`) are resolved in mid-registration of components using a `LifetimeScopes`, which might affect more advanced dependency structures with `LifetimeScopes`.

Comment: I cannot compile it. I have following message:`'Autofac.IComponentContext' does not contain a definition for 'BeginLifetimeScope'`

Comment: One more thing. If I use your solution and create `FirstViewModel` then just before resolving dependency all `EFContext` instances will be disposed, because of using statement.

Comment: I've just noticed, that you modified your answer. But I'm not happy with such solution. Resolving `FirstViewModel` or `SecondViewModel` isn't so easy. And in my opinion you don't get all pros of having Dependency Container

Comment: So what you want is to register the ViewModels too, using the ContainerBuilder? Because after your own answer I thought that resolving them using a scope was good enough. I'll try to think of a better solution then.

Comment: Alright, I've changed the implementation to register the ViewModels in the container. But as I mentioned at the end, I'm not quite sure how this may affect registration in more complex situations. Could you see if this works for you?